# linq error Defined default value for hashset

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I Defined this query to return `IEnumerable<Estructura>`

```
 (from d in db.Direccion
  where d.Activo == true
  select new Estructura()
  {
      IdEstructura = d.IdDireccion,
      Descripcion = d.Descripcion,
              IdPadre = 0,
      lstEstructurasHijos = d.Cliente.Select(C => new Estructura()
      {
          IdEstructura = C.IdCliente,
          Descripcion = C.Descripcion,
          IdPadre = C.IdDireccion,
          lstEstructurasHijos = C.Campana.Select(Ca => new Estructura()
          {
              IdEstructura = Ca.IdCampana,
              Descripcion = Ca.Descripcion,
              IdPadre = Ca.IdCliente,
              lstEstructurasHijos = Ca.Servicio.Select(S => new Estructura()
              {
                  IdEstructura = S.IdServicio,
                  Descripcion = S.Descripcion,
                  IdPadre = S.IdCampana,
                  lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>()
              })
          })
      })
  } into query
  select query);
```

And this the class related

```
 public class Estructura
 {
    public Estructura()
    {
        this.lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>();
    }

    public int IdEstructura { get; set; }
    public int IdPadre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Estructura> lstEstructurasHijos { get;set;}
 }
```

It throws this error

> `System.NotSupportedException`: The type '`Estructura`' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Why am I doing wrong? Because if i remove the instance Estructura of each element and let the anonymous type the linq works well

**Update**

So, I made a few changes in the query but i found this error now

> could not create '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1`'. Only allow primitive ('como Int32, String y Guid') in this context

How can I Defined a default empty `hashset` for this `Ienumerable`

Comment: can you post the anonymous type variant? The error message refers to a `Member` identifier that isn't in the code shown. I suspect the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Sorry I modified the question...

Comment: Wow, I love that error message.  It essentially says *"A type cannot be initialized in two places in the same query."*

Comment: Hi, in other words I can't do nothing to modified the query and handle this error?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yeah, and the operative words are `LINQ to Entities`

Comment: @sehe: Are you saying that Linq to Entities is known for these kind of caveats?  In this case, is the answer "If it breaks when you do that, then don't do that"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm not experienced with Linq-to-Entities, otherwise I might have answered it. I just wanted to highlight the part of the message (with the only reference to EF being in the tag, it was easy to miss). Apart from EF, there was nothing wrong I could see with this code. My gut says, this is (yet another) limitation of Linq-to-_XXX_ providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Entity Framework is having trouble **translating your query into something that can be executed at the store** (on the database server, I'm guessing). EF is good but not perfect at such translations; sometimes it needs to be given some help.

Here I think we can achieve what you want by:

- first retrieving all the relevant data;
- then building the hierarchy locally

So something like this:

```
var data = 
    db.Direccion
    .Include("Cliente.Campana.Servicio")
    .Where(d => d.Activo)
    .ToList();
```

The `Include` makes sure that all the related child entities are retrieved in this query, rather than lazily on demand. The `ToList` forces the query to be evaluated, and leaves us with `data` as an **in-memory** `List<Direccion>`.

Then we can just do

```
var enumerable = 
    (from d in data
     select new Estructura
     {
     // etc as your original statement
```

which will be evaluated by standard linq-to-objects, which won't have a problem with your hierarchy construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
var q = (from d in db.Direccion
  where d.Activo == true
  select new
  {
      IdEstructura = d.IdDireccion,
      Descripcion = d.Descripcion,
      IdPadre = 0,
      lstEstructurasHijos = d.Cliente.Select(C => new
      {
          IdEstructura = C.IdCliente,
          Descripcion = C.Descripcion,
          IdPadre = C.IdDireccion,
          lstEstructurasHijos = C.Campana.Select(Ca => new 
          {
              IdEstructura = Ca.IdCampana,
              Descripcion = Ca.Descripcion,
              IdPadre = Ca.IdCliente,
              lstEstructurasHijos = Ca.Servicio.Select(S => new
              {
                  IdEstructura = S.IdServicio,
                  Descripcion = S.Descripcion,
                  IdPadre = S.IdCampana
              })
          })
      })
  } into query
  select query).ToList();
var result = q.Select(d=>new Estructura
  {
      IdEstructura = d.IdEstructura,
      Descripcion = d.Descripcion,
      IdPadre = d.IdPadre,
      lstEstructurasHijos = d.Cliente.Select(C => new Estructura
      {
          IdEstructura = C.IdEstructura,
          Descripcion = C.Descripcion,
          IdPadre = C.IdPadre,
          lstEstructurasHijos = C.Campana.Select(Ca => new Estructura
          {
              IdEstructura = Ca.IdEstructura,
              Descripcion = Ca.Descripcion,
              IdPadre = Ca.IdPadre,
              lstEstructurasHijos = Ca.Servicio.Select(S => new Estructura
              {
                  IdEstructura = S.IdEstructura,
                  Descripcion = S.Descripcion,
                  IdPadre = S.IdPadre
              })
          })
      })
  }
```

It's work for me

> How can I Defined a default empty hashset for this Ienumerable?

Just delete `lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>()` from query and allow constructor initialize empty list

```
 public class Estructura
 {
    public Estructura()
    {
        //!!!
        this.lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>();
    }
    //...
 }
```